# If container has children of a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a live search function, but I need to hide any containers that do not have a match.

This is a sample of how the containers are populated if nothing is entered in the search bar. ***EDIT: This will be identical even if there is a string in the search bar. `fadeOut()` hides the element, doesn't remove it.***

```
<div id="Alabama_container" class="state-container">
   <h1>Alabama</h1>
   <div id="330_store-object" class="store-object" style="">
      <h4>Store 330 - Birmingham</h4>
      <p>(205) 981-1320</p>
      <p>5201 US-280, Birmingham, AL 35242, USA</p>
      <button id="330_store-object-link" class="button">View on Map</button><button id="330_store-object-floorPlan" class="button">Floorplans</button>
   </div>
   <div id="337_store-object" class="store-object" style="">
      <h4>Store 337 - Dothan</h4>
      <p>(334) 671-1370</p>
      <p>4401 Montgomery Hwy #300, Dothan, AL 36303, USA</p>
      <button id="337_store-object-link" class="button">View on Map</button><button id="337_store-object-floorPlan" class="button">Floorplans</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

The `state-container` elements are generated on the DOM first then `store-object` elements are appended to the appropriately named `state-container`.

**Search Function Sample:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#store-search").keyup(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val(),
            count = 0;
        $(".store-object").each(function () {

            // If the store object doesn't match, remove it
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

                // Show the store objects that do match the query
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Results counter for troubleshooting
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text(count + "Results Founds");
    });
});
```

My search function simply uses **filter** to determine any matching strings within the `store-object` elements and hides any that don't match. However, the matches still reside in their `state-container` so what you end up with is a list of states without any results inside.

[image]

What I want to do is loop through `state-container` elements and determine if it contains any `store-object` children so I can handle it appropriately. What would I use to achieve this?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for this

Comment: @SudarpoChong It should be trivial for you to copy OP's code to a blank JSFiddle, should you wish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different ways to achieve what you want. One of which would be using the `:visible` selector and then hiding the state-container on an empty set.

```
$('.state-container').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('.store-object:visible').length === 0){
       $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Keep in mind, you'll need to run that *after* all of the children's fadeOut animations have completed.

Another approach would be to keep a tally of the hidden elements as you go through the search, and if all children were hidden remove the parent.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.state-container').each(function(){
        $(this).data('total', $(this).find('.store-object').length);//set a count of total
        
    });
    $("#store-search").keyup(function () {
        var filter = $(this).val(),
            count = 0;
        //reset the hidden count for the states
        $('.state-container').each(function(){
            $(this).data('hidden', 0);//initialize to 0
            $(this).show();
        });
        
        $(".store-object").each(function () {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            
            // If the store object doesn't match, remove it
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
                parent.data('hidden', parent.data('hidden') + 1);//increment hidden count
                // Show the store objects that do match the query
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
            
            if(parent.data('hidden') == parent.data('total')){
              parent.hide();
            }
        });

        // Results counter for troubleshooting
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text(count + "Results Founds");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='store-search' />
<div id="Alabama_container" class="state-container">
   <h1>Alabama</h1>
   <div id="330_store-object" class="store-object" style="">
      <h4>Store 330 - Birmingham</h4>
      <p>(205) 981-1320</p>
      <p>5201 US-280, Birmingham, AL 35242, USA</p>
      <button id="330_store-object-link" class="button">View on Map</button><button id="330_store-object-floorPlan" class="button">Floorplans</button>
   </div>
   <div id="337_store-object" class="store-object" style="">
      <h4>Store 337 - Dothan</h4>
      <p>(334) 671-1370</p>
      <p>4401 Montgomery Hwy #300, Dothan, AL 36303, USA</p>
      <button id="337_store-object-link" class="button">View on Map</button><button id="337_store-object-floorPlan" class="button">Floorplans</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Regarding Approach 1: This approach accounts for my fundamental error as well, so I'm using this. It is working, however, wondering if you have any advice; I've added a conditional to ```show()``` when visible elements exist, but once the containers are hidden they seem to be permanently hidden. I assume it may be a timing issue.

Comment: @CodeSpent you'll have to `show` the parent before you do another `:visible` check or else none of the children will be visible. You _may_ still have a timing issue.. IDK about how jquery will handle it internally. I also updated my answer with a sample to give you an idea of the second approach in case that ends up being easier for you.

Comment: I'm comparing the 2 methods now and will follow up, thank you. It does seem to be timing so I'm seeing what I can do to expand my window a bit to allow everything to finish up before proceeding with another check.

Comment: Well, its really ugly, but the only way I could allow JQuery to properly align with the keyUp window was to add ```$(this).show();``` as the very first action within the looping of ```state-container``` elements so it forces a ```show();``` on every action unless the next condition is met. Using if/else or just if statements wouldn't allow it to be read before hiding it again. Thanks for your help, accepting approach 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if store-container has store-object and then only loop through them like:

```
$(".store-container").find(".store-object").length &&
$(".store-object").each(function () {
```

After your edit, I could say that you should check for visible length like:

```
$(".state-container").find(".store-object:visible").length &&
```

But, I would still say that you don't need to check anything because you're already checking for the condition that if it's visible then only fadeOut. That is, even if this is hidden, there's nothing problem using fadeOut. But what I can say is that you can pause the search execution:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
// your each function
}, 600);
```